# Execute pythonscript from JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, raspberry-pi

I just learned how to make this multi state button in HTML and JavaSctipt (you could call me a n00b).  I've been trying to learn and adopt from others who have asked similar questions, however I wanted to ask if I'm doing this correctly.

Below is my HTML, can you let me know if this would correctly execute the python code when the button is being clicked and continue to execute the script until the button is no longer being clicked (held)?

If you're curious, this is the beginning of web a page hosted on my Raspberry Pi to be used with webiopi to control a relay board.  The below code is intended to control a single button (more buttons to come).

```js
function changeImage() {
  document.images["gabe-up"].src = "assets/up-over.png";
  return true;
}

function changeImageBack() {
  document.images["gabe-up"].src = "assets/up.png";
  return true;
}

function handleMDown() {
  document.images["gabe-up"].src = "assets/up-pressed.png";
  $.ajax({
    url: 'python/gabe-up.py',
    success: loadDataSuccess,
    error: loadError
  });
  return true;
}

function handleMUp() {
  changeImage();
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" <title>Desk Control</title>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="#" onMouseOver="return changeImage()" onMouseOut="return changeImageBack()" onMouseDown="return handleMDown()" onMouseUp="return handleMUp()">
    <img name="gabe-up" src="assets/up.png" width="110" height="110" border="0" alt="Gabe Up">
  </a>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: `function handleMDown()` will not execute the Python script. Rather, it will most likely return the contents of `python/gabe-up.py`.

Comment: You need a web server that can run python codes and return a response.then you can fetch the results from that web server using ajax. take a look at [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html). You have to use a different port if you are running the regular server and python server on the same host/PC